# Gradle Building Non-Stop

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

[My Gradle building since yesterday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBWGM.png) My gradle has been building for more than 6 Hours now, I really have no idea of what is going on. Please help.

I tried to disable the proxy but it gives me this: [Proxy Disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4SqG.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on android studio 1.5 then upgrade to version 2 because 1.5 takes more time for graddle building.